# PHP file won't run from HTML

Tags: php, html

I have this very simple code. Its supposed to go to google when i click on enter, but the php code just pops up on a blank screen. It doesnt execute?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>


<body>

  <form name="form" action="test.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Car Loan">
  </form>

</body>



</html>
```

```
<?php header('Location: http://google.dk') exit; ?>
```

Comment: I'm guessing this two is in different files?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, be sure you put the PHP code in files whose termination is `.php`, then check if the web server is configured to run PHP scripts.

You can do this check easily. Write `<?php phpinfo();` in a new file (let's name it `info.php`) and open the file in the browser through the webserver (`http://localhost/info.php` f.e.). If you see the raw source of the file then your server is not configured to run PHP scripts.

---

Your PHP script has [syntax errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071/4265352). A semicolon is missing after the call to the [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function and that prevents it to run.

```
<?php
header('Location: http://google.dk');
exit;
```

You should enable [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and [error logging](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) in your [`php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) and check the [`errors log`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) frequently (ideally keep a `tail -f php_errors.log` always running in a terminal window).

Comment: While true, that wouldn't cause the source code to be displayed in the browser. It would show a 500 internal server error, so this isn't an answer to the problem described in this question.

Comment: @Quentin I guess those blank screen exactly 500 error

Comment: @AlexSlipknot — The question says "**the php code just pops up** on a blank screen". I'll grant you that "blank screen" is a weird way of saying "white background" though.

Comment: @Quentin xD well I heard a lot of times about "blank" so In this case it can be "white background". But we don't know sure while hi doesn't explain :)

Comment: Sorry if it wasnt clear. Yes it is a white background, where all my php code is displayed. My coding teacher told me, that even tho PHP is a server side language, it can be ran from a file on the computer. I've used PHP for quite some time, but only on MAMP localhost. Never tried clientside in a file, and i guess that doesnt work unless it does??